# Pacman game - Making a wall block his movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I'm making a pacman game with Jquery. Pacman's movement is directed by the arrow keys, which triggers a setInterval() that makes him move his width's distance repeatedly, giving the illusion that he is moving Completely straight. Pressing a new key clears the interval and starts him moving somewhere else.

```
function Player(){

  this.left = $('#pacMan').css('left');
/**/  
   this.top = $('#pacMan').css('top'); 
/**/  
  this.rightMove = function(){

if (){
  this.left = parseInt(this.left) + 20;  
 $('#pacMan').animate({'left': this.left}, 100);   
}


};
```

//The object containing the movement method. The empty if statement is the problem I'll get to later.

```
var timer;
$('body').keydown(function () {
 var key = event.which;
  window.clearInterval(timer);
  timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    switch (key) {
    case 37:

      pacMan.leftMove();

      break;
```

// The keydown function. It's all kind of disjointed, I know.

So the above works fine. My issue however is this: What happens if I put a wall? How would I get him to stop? I am able to do it with one block but not many. Let me explain.

So I have the whole thing laid out on a grid that's the width of pacman. Me appending a div child to one of the grids selects the grid boxes next to it and puts it in an array. My original if statement was that if Pacman's position is shared with the position of the neighboring grid's, one of his movements are disabled.So if he is just left of the block he can't move right, giving the illusion that the block is stopping him from moving.
e.g

```
If(Pacman.position().left !== gridBox120.position.left(){
pacMan.moveRight()
}
else{
clearInterval()
}
```

//As long as pacman is not in the spot right next to the block, he can move right.

This works. But what if I want multiple blocks on the stage? How could I get all these things blocks in the if statement? Or would that be the best way to do it?

My plan was to put the neighbouring divs ID in an array and if Pacman's position shares the position of any of the ID's of the items in the array, he can't move right.

I have no idea how to do this. Some sort of iteration? Or maybe an array is not the best idea for this?

If this is not explained properly I'll respond to comments.

[Image link. yellow is pacman. purple are the neighbor divs that are sent to arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KaiC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

i already did something like this for a brick breaker. 
I've tested obj and array for storing blocks. Array is far faster than obj. 
My method was : store all the grid in arrays
And verify after each move the left-1, left+1, top-1 and top+1

```
if (grid[left-1][top] == "block" && move == "left") {
Pacman.stopFunction()
}
```